# `$location` causes page to hang after redirect with `$http` Interceptor?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-http, json-web-token, angular1.6

Can anyone help me understand why my `authInterceptor`, upon a `401` or `500` error, redirects OK (using `$location`) but the page seems to hang aftewards, and the response does not seem completed? Does sending back `$q.reject(rejection)` in the code below complete the request? What am I doing wrong?

*Note: this project is using Angular v1.6.2*

```
app.factory('authInterceptor', function($q, tokenService, $location) {
  return {
    request: function(config) {
      token = tokenService.getToken();
      if (token) {
        // If token, send authorization jwt header:
        console.log("Authorizing token...");
        config.headers.Authorization = "Bearer " + token;
      }

      return config;
    },

    responseError: function(rejection) {
      console.log("THIS IS THE RESPONSE ERROR:");
      if (rejection.status == 401 || rejection.status == 500) {
        console.log("401 ERROR DUDE...REDIRECTION");
        $location.url('/');
      }
      return $q.reject(rejection);
    }
  };
})
```

Comment: I think it does complete the request (can't test it right now). Check [this part of AngularJS code](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/72a87ceda7ae7a08b69fbc23dc6a3620f249493d/src/ng/http.js#L998) that handles the interceptors chain. After you send back your rejection it executes [this function](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/a03b75c6a812fcc2f616fc05c0f1710e03fca8e9/src/ng/browser.js#L46) which might be interfering in your expected behavior.

Comment: +Samir Aguiar -- I think you're right that it does complete the request. I think the page hang, from what I can tell, is actually a bug I didn't notice before, that was present PRIOR to building my interceptor. So, something funky is going on that I have to keep researching--spent a lot of time yesterday evening wrestling it and about to get back to it--seems to only be present in Safari (the load bar hangs after a user is re-directed when attempting to access a back-end page). One of those bugs I wish I'd noticed way earlier! Thank you for all the links and response, was very helpful!

Comment: No worries, glad I could help. And good luck finding that nasty bug :)